# Voltage Across NMOS and PMOS Transistors

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

[image]

So I have the question above concerning an NMOS and PMOS transistor. The goal is to find V1 and V2 in steady state. My understanding is that because the gate voltages of zero and Vdd are there, the transistors are "on" and current flows.

- Is the idea here simply that the voltage will get as close to 1.2 as possible for each V1 and V2, until such a voltage would cause VGS to be below the threshold voltage?
- So for example here V1 would reach 1.2V as PMOS is on. But V2 would reach only 0.8V because any increase past 0.8 would mean VGS < Vt. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that reasoning is correct.

Comment: How do I know which side of the transistor is the source and which is the drain?

Comment: For a PMOS transistor, the side with higher voltage is the source. For an NMOS transistor, the side with lower voltage is the source. The notions of "source" and "drain" have no physical significance in VLSI design with 4-terminal transistors.